# Python: Venn diagram from score data

Tags: python, venn

I have the following data:

```
df =
id testA testB
1  3     NA
1  1     3
2  2     NA
2  NA    1
2  0     0
3  NA    NA
3  1     1
```

I would like to create a Venn diagram of the number of times that testA and testB appear, testA but not testB, and testB but not testA.

The expected outcome would be the following groups:

[image]

```
Both tests: 3
A but not B: 2
B but not A: 1
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the expected output for the sample input data you have provided

Comment: Isn't this trivial? Just create a check/query for each combination and apply it on the data

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: @Shuba has to be because he named the variable df

Comment: yes using pandas. A bit trivial it is actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not sure how you get to your index in the dataframe, or if you have another index. Also, I assumed *NA* to be np.nan.

In any case, you can try something like the following (but start where your df exists). First, I try to recreate your DataFrame. Then, i create two sets, namely setA and setB, which contain the indices of where the data is not nan. Finally, a Venn diagram is created, containing these two sets.

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame()
df["testA"] = [3,1,2,np.nan,0,np.nan,1]
df["testB"] = [np.nan,3,np.nan,1,0,np.nan,1]

setA = set([index_ for index_ in df.index if not np.isnan(df["testA"].loc[index_])])
setB = set([index_ for index_ in df.index if not np.isnan(df["testB"].loc[index_])])
venn2([setA, setB])
```

[You then get something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgdJO.png)

Answer (score 1):

So you'd probably want to use the speed of pandas for that, and not cast to python object.
In pandas we can give filter conditions, so copying and modifying @Lukas answer -

```py
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame()
df["testA"] = [3,1,2,np.nan,0,np.nan,1]
df["testB"] = [np.nan,3,np.nan,1,0,np.nan,1]

setA = set([index_ for index_ in df.index if not np.isnan(df["testA"].loc[index_])])
setB = set([index_ for index_ in df.index if not np.isnan(df["testB"].loc[index_])])

both = df[df["testB"].notnull()| df["testA"].notnull()]
either = df[df["testB"].notnull()& df["testA"].notnull()]
right_side = df[df["testB"].notnull()]
```

Each give you part of the van diagram.
Then you can `len(var)` to see how many results it gave you.